# Scrapy & Selenium: How To Loop XPATH and preform a click

Tags: python, loops, selenium, xpath, scrapy

I've been working on scraping [this](https://www.investiere.ch/companies/all) site using selenium and scrapy. I want my code to click on each company link and follow then extract and loop this process. but I can't figure out how to go from one company link to another.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from selenium import webdriver
import scrapy
import time


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'comp'
    allowed_domains = ['site']
    start_urls = ["site"]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        index = 0
        while True:
            companies = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="company-list"]/ul/li')
            try:
                companies[index].click()
                time.sleep(6)
            except IndexError:
                break
            resp = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
            for com in resp.xpath('body'):
                yield \
                    {
                 # DO Something
                     } 

                self.driver.back()
                index += 1
            self.driver.quit()
```

It extracts from the first link only then it stops. Please Help Me.

Comment: Do you insist on using Selenium? This page seems to be using an API - try to look in browser's developer tools for XHR requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, try to use their API, you won't have to bother with page rendering, clicking elements etc. Looking on XHR request in developer tools, you can see that:

1. To get the list of companies, call https://www.investiere.ch/proxy/api2/v1/companies?extra%5Bimagecache%5D=company_logo_70&fields=companyType,lifecycle&page=0&parameters%5Binclude_skipped%5D=yes. Clicking *Load more...* just adjusts the `page` parameter in URL.
2. From the result above, you can extract company details by following link in attribute `records[X].uri`, for example for the first company *CombaGroup* it's https://www.investiere.ch/api2/v1/companies/10211.
3. To get the list of people (e.g. Managers), follow link https://www.investiere.ch/proxy/api2/v1/companies/10211/people.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is because you have
 `driver.quit()` inside your while loop. Take it out of loop.

Also prefer using exact xpath if you are using it to extract copany name as below,

```
//*[@id="company-list"]/ul/li/div[2]/h4
```

Comment: I took driver.quit() out of the loop but it didn't solve the problem and I want to scrap not only company name but their website and Board Advisers too.

Comment: now what is the problem, is it still running only once or giving some error?

Comment: Yeah, It is still running only once.